# problem on RBDL s library by using ACADO?

Tags: c++

I am using ACADO for an optimal control problem. I already wright the ocp and the process with ACADO. But my algorithm does not achieved. Have you ever heard about a problem with RBDL library by using ACADO ? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, problem is in your code.

Comment: in fact when I change the order of my library once it is ACADO that converged but fowardsDynamics doesn't work and once it is the contrary. So my code works because it converged.... but I can t have both ACADO and fowardsDynamics succeed